# Low traffic Nginx on AWS Ubuntu 11.10 EC2, returns 499 when tested by monit, why?

Tags: nginx, monit

I have a very low traffic Nginx box that serves as a reverse proxy to an external service.  I have Monit on the box to restart `nginx` if it crashes.  Needless to say, `nginx` stops at least once a day on this machine, and `monit` has to restart it.

Here's my `monit` configuration:

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 80% for 25 cycles then restart
    if totalmem > 400.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
    if children > 250 then restart
    if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
    if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80 protocol http
       then restart
    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Here's my site config on `nginx`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  somedomainname.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://somedomainname.com;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Needless to say"? There must be a reason for this. What do your logs show?

Comment: Nginx shows a 499 in the logs for the monit tests, which according to wikipedia means: Used in Nginx logs to indicate when the connection has been closed by client while the server is still processing its request, making server unable to send a status code back.

How do I get monit to not close the connection, and why is that happening?  It doesn't happen all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be due to `monit` not sending a 'Host:' header field. Try addressing this by setting up a `location` for `monit` to monitor that is not proxied:

```
location = /test_target.html {
    root /var/www/public;
}
```

*(I found this answer by searching for [nginx monit 499](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=monit+nginx+499). It was the first result.)*